# What is metadata_account in mpl_token_metadata::instruction::create_metadata_accounts_v3?

Tags: mpl-token-metadata

I am trying to create Metadata for an NFT. I found this function and the second parameter is "metadata_account". I have been looking everywhere trying to find what this is. I thought I was creating the metadata, so I'm really confused what its asking for.

My guess:
To create a new mint, I passed in a newly generated Keypair pubkey, is this similar, where I just pass in a newly created Pubkey?

[image: mpl_token_metadata::instruction::create_metadata_accounts_v3 Documentation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`metadata_account` is the account that stores the metadata for the `mint` and is a PDA.
[image]

From the client you can derive it using `@metaplex-foundation/js`:

```
const metadataAccountAddress = await metaplex
  .nfts()
  .pdas()
  .metadata({ mint: mintAddress }) // pubkey of the mint
```

If you are creating the metadata account via a CPI in Anchor, you can also validate the account address using `mpl_token_metadata` crate.

```
use mpl_token_metadata::pda::find_metadata_account
```

```
///CHECK:
#[account(
    mut,
    address=find_metadata_account(&mint.key()).0
)]
pub metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>
```